# Countdown timer that doesn't restart when page refresh

Tags: javascript

Well, basically that. I'm setting up a promo code for my store, and I want to put a timer for that promo, so people feel the need to buy before the promo ends.
I have the code, and it's already functional and all, but the thing is that it'll restart on page refresh, and I already looked other answers and stuff, but I can't figure out how to put the cookie thing in my code, since that's what all the pages say.

Thanks!

My code is

```
  function getTimeRemaining(endtime) {
  var t = Date.parse(endtime) - Date.parse(new Date());
  var seconds = Math.floor((t / 1000) % 60);
  var minutes = Math.floor((t / 1000 / 60) % 60);
  var hours = Math.floor((t / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);
  var days = Math.floor(t / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  return {
    'total': t,
    'days': days,
    'hours': hours,
    'minutes': minutes,
    'seconds': seconds
  };
}

function initializeClock(id, endtime) {
  var clock = document.getElementById(id);
  var daysSpan = clock.querySelector('.days');
  var hoursSpan = clock.querySelector('.hours');
  var minutesSpan = clock.querySelector('.minutes');
  var secondsSpan = clock.querySelector('.seconds');

  function updateClock() {
    var t = getTimeRemaining(endtime);

    daysSpan.innerHTML = t.days;
    hoursSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.hours).slice(-2);
    minutesSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.minutes).slice(-2);
    secondsSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.seconds).slice(-2);

    if (t.total <= 0) {
      clearInterval(timeinterval);
    }
  }

  updateClock();
  var timeinterval = setInterval(updateClock, 1000);
}

var deadline = new Date(Date.parse(new Date()) + 15 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
initializeClock('clockdiv', deadline);
```

....

And my website is: http://sevenpartes.com/

Comment: JavaScript != Java

Comment: You need to have a server-side language to keep the timer from resetting because right now JavaScript is only executing that script in memory and not being stored anywhere.

Comment: Why not just hard-code the endtime? You know the exact time your promo ends, don't you?

Comment: How can I hard-code the endtime? It would stop it from restarting?

Answer (score 0):

A non-server option would be to save the timer start time in local storage and then check local storage for an active timer every time the page loads. You would clear out the local storage when the timer expires.

One downside of this approach is that it would in theory be hackable - someone could edit the local variable. You could encode it somehow, but an examination of the source code would reveal how to crack it.

Answer (score 0):

Save the deadline to a cookie. [How to read and write to cookies with javascript](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp).

The guide proposes two functions:

```
function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
    var expires = "expires="+d.toUTCString();
    document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";" + expires + ";path=/";
}

function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
            c = c.substring(1);
        }
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
            return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
        }
    }
    return "";
}
```

Which could be used as follows

```
$(window).load(function(){
    var deadline = new Date( getCookie('deadline') );
    // If the deadline is NaN, it has not been set.
    if( isNaN(deadline.getTime()) )
    {
        // Set the deadline to one day from now (86400000ms)
        deadline = new Date( Date.now() + 86400000 );
        setCookie('deadline', deadline.toUTCString());
    }
    // The deadline is expired
    if( deadline.getTime() < Date.now() ) 
    {
        // Handle this / set deadline to a new time
    }

    // Set the countdown timer on the page
    myCountDownTimer.setDeadline( deadline );
}
```

Comment: Thanks! But... how can I add that to my code? since my java knowledge is so basic, this one is an old code I had and just fix minor things but I can't really figure the whole thing out.

Comment: @AKUPOID I updated the answer with a more in-depth implementation

Comment: Thank you, again. So, I used the code, and the clock just stopped, and the numbers disappeared. I probably I used it the wrong way?

Comment: @AKUPOID Theres a probability that the format for time that your clock uses is different from the format for time I used in my example. Other than that prediction, I would have to see the code to understand the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Just a disclaimer, you absolutely need a server-side solution to prevent anyone from bypassing the time limit for your promo. It is also the only way you can make your code here reliable, but that being said, here's my answer to your question.

You can statically set the end time for your promo by replacing the second to last line of your code with the following code. Be sure to change the numbers to align with the end date of your promo.

```
//The parameters to the below function are year, month minus 1, and day
var deadline = new Date(2018, 6, 1); //This is actually July 1st
```

If you want to have the timeout only start when they first visit, then reference the other answers about using cookies.

Once you start using a server-side language, such as PHP, then you can dynamically generate those 3 numbers that go into the Date object to set its value from whatever database you setup. If your customers are purchasing from your site, then you'll also need to check on the server-side whether the promo is over or not. Because, checking only on the client-side can be easily bypassed.

Comment: Thank you! Now my clock isn't restarting on refresh, however... when the count hits zero...it'll start over? Maybe I'm wrong, but since the deadline was july 1st, it'll restart over and over till july 1st?! and...I would like to now about the server-side, since I've been thinking that the code should disappear after the clock stops because if it's there...what's the point of the countdown anyway...

Comment: Sorry about that, I was just looking for an easy snippet of code that you could include into what you already had. I would enclose the initializeClock call (the last statement) within an if statement that checks whether or not the deadline for the promo has passed.

Comment: @user806799Ok, so... I know what an If statement is, but no sure how to use it in my code. 'Cause basically the thing would be that with the If statement IF the deadline is met, it should do something, right? like...hide de promo? that's what you meant?

Comment: @AKUPOID Yes, that's exactly what I meant.

Comment: I have zero idea on how to put the if statement inside my code, I tried and the clock just disappears so probably I'm doing it wrong! But thank you very much for your help!